# How to change the status field when the date and time is over then current date time in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5

I have a reservation vehicle application using laravel. It has departure date time, and when now is the time, the reservation status change into closed. Do you know how to do it? I have to update the status in database too. I am already made an update function to update the status in database but I don't know where to put because I don't know how to update the status without click button closed or another button?

[image]

Comment: use `Task Scheduling` https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling

Comment: I have tried, but do I have to run a command in terminal to execute that task scheduling? I mean I already put the code in kernel.php and test the time, the status did not change when the time is over. But when I run the command php artisan in the terminal, the status successfully changed.

Comment: If you are using linux, use crontab to run cron job. You can read about cron on [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: Please see my update answer.

Answer (score 2):

In order to change status base on the time, you have to use [Laravel Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling).

If you are using Linux, use crontab to run cron job. You can read about cron on [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

If you still don't understand, you can also read [How to set up Cron job in Laravel](https://scotch.io/@Kidalikevin/how-to-set-up-cron-job-in-laravel) via scotch.io

If you want to setup cron job on window OS, you can read it on [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/setting-up-cron-for-drupal/configuring-cron-jobs-with-windows).